# What happens if you fall into gold in the underground maze in Inherit the Earth

Tags: inherit-the-earth

In the game `Inherit the Earth` there is an underground maze. Riff of the Fox Tribe must find the exit so that he can save his friends. The maze is a raised brick platform in water. It also includes a giant Komodo dragon which tries to knock the user off of the platform. If you look down at the water, I believe there are certain areas which are spiked, but there is also a large area where instead of water, there is a massive pile of gold.

What happens if the Komodo dragon knocks Riff into the pile of gold instead of into the water?